# Adding elements to a linked list C

Tags: c, linked-list

Recently I've started doing this program in c and came up with a problem. I can't find why the list only has 1 element.

I am creating a list so that all parts of linked list would be letters of "problem" array and there would not be any duplicates.

Any help would be appreciated.

This is my function where I create a list:

```
void createAlphabet(ALPHABET **head, char *problem, int *error){
ALPHABET *current=NULL;
int length = strlen(problem);
int i;
for (i=0;i<length;i++){
    if(isalpha(problem[i])){
        if(current==NULL){
            current=(ALPHABET*)malloc(sizeof(ALPHABET));
            current->next=NULL;
            current->letter=problem[i];
            (*head)=current;
        }
        else{
            current=(*head);
            while(problem[i]!=current->letter && current->next!=NULL){
                current=current->next;
            }
            if(problem[i]!=current->letter){
                current=current->next;
                current=(ALPHABET*)malloc(sizeof(ALPHABET));
                current->next=NULL;
                current->letter=problem[i];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to debug this yourself? If not you might like to read this: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Also it might be interesting to know, what your test "string" is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in :

```
if(problem[i]!=current->letter){
            current=current->next;
            current=(ALPHABET*)malloc(sizeof(ALPHABET));
            current->next=NULL;
            current->letter=problem[i];
        }
```

In `current=whatever;current=(ALPHABET*)malloc(sizeof(ALPHABET));` , `malloc()` modifies `current` but it does not change `whatever`.

Try :

```
 if(problem[i]!=current->letter){

            current->next=malloc(sizeof(ALPHABET));
            if(current->next==NULL){printf("malloc failed\n");exit(1);}
            current=current->next;
            current->next=NULL;
            current->letter=problem[i];
        }
```